# Condition within mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to loop through records using MySQL query, keep in mind this process has to take place in the database so i can not use the best alternative which would be Python.

```
Table_a

#animalid calvdate lactationid 
animal_A 2015-06-12 1
animal_A 2017-06-10 2
animal_B 2018-08-10 1

Table_b   

 #animalid milkdate morningmilk midmilk eveningmilk

    animal_A 2018-02-16 8 0 8
    animal_A 2016-02-12 12 0 12
```

my query

```
   SELECT *, calvdate FROM Table_b
    INNER JOIN Table_a ON Table_b.animalid = Table_a.animalid
    WHERE TO_DAYS(milkdate) - TO_DAYS(calvdate)<400
   GROUP BY Table_b.animalid and milkdate
```

output of my query

```
#animalid milkdate morningmilk midmilk eveningmilk calvdate
    animal_A 2018-02-16 8 0 8 2015-06-12
```

How can i capture all the records from table_b that fit into the 400 day margin without truncating the right records from table_b
expected output:

```
 #animalid milkdate morningmilk midmilk eveningmilk calvdate
        animal_A 2018-02-16 8 0 8 2015-06-12
        animal_A 2017-02-12 12 0 12 2017-06-10
```

Comment: What do you mean with **without truncating the right records from table_b**

Comment: What's that group by supposed to achieve. And can you add your expected output please.

Comment: group by is supposed to get rid of duplicates

Comment: That's not a good use of group by use distinct instead and read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Note that `WHERE TO_DAYS(milkdate) - TO_DAYS(calvdate)<400` will probably include rows you don't want, as the condition doesn't take into account situations where calvdate is after milkdate.

Comment: Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for sample data. (Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub select query that would return all records from the first table and the values that fit from the second table.

```
select animalid as testday_animalid, milkdate, 
(select calvdate as calvdate from lactationmaster where animalid = testday_animalid and calvdate < milkdate order by calvdate desc limit 1) as calvdate
from view_testlact
order by milkdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is an operator. The expression `Table_b.animalid and milkdate` casts the arguments to booleans and takes the logical conjunction (which will always be 0). Consequently, every row in the result is in the same group, which is why you only see one in the result.

To group by multiple columns, use a comma:

```
GROUP BY Table_b.animalid, milkdate
```